# Calling the mixpanel API never returns a response

Tags: python, python-requests, mixpanel

When I use the following Python code to call the Mixpanel API, I never get a response.

```
import requests
requests.get("https://data.mixpanel.com/")
```

But when I try in the browser it works fine. (I get the following response: `{error: "Not Found"}` which is expected.)

Why is this? Or what can I do to locate the problem?

**Edit:**

- After a while I get the following error:

  ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.mixpanel.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by : [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer)
- urllib2 also does not return any response.

Comment: When I visit `https://data.mixpanel.com` in my browser I get `{"error": "Not found"}`. Are you logging into a website and then visiting that? If so you likely need to perform the same workflow with requests. Requests can't just pull your cookies out of your browser session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@elgehelge This seems to be an SSL issue with your version of python of OSX that is similar to this: https://github.com/chrippa/livestreamer/issues/819

Try installing python to version 2.7.9 and the upgrading security packages:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade certifi pyopenssl requests[security] ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 pip
```

Comment: I have not idea why that works since I have the same problem using urllib2 (see updated question). But it works, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

OP: Are you harnessing the response struct from requests.get ?
What do you get when you run:

```
import requests
result = requests.get("https://data.mixpanel.com/")
print result.text
```

(requests.get returns an object that you can then query ...)

Be sure to see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
for more examples of how to use the requests library.

Comment: I simply cannot do that since I never get any response.
I have the same problem using urllib2